# Why doesn't df.append( ) work in my for loop?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, select, append

I'm trying to extract data for a list of counties using a for loop. However, it's not working at all. `DATA` only contains the 21 rows for Orange County after the loop.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/7ifvvpyy23sa2fciuvcygehakxlnnv')

COUNTIES = ['Orange','Los Angeles','Imperial']
DATA = df.loc[df['county']==COUNTIES[0]]
for cnty in COUNTIES[1:]:
    DATA.append(df.loc[df['county']==cnty], ignore_index=True)

print(DATA.shape)
print(DATA)
```

Can somebody tell me what went wrong? I tried

```
df.loc[df['county']=='Orange'].append(df.loc[df['county']=='Los Angeles'])
```

and it worked fine. But

```
DATA.append(df.loc[df['county']=='Los Angeles'])
```

simply did nothing. What happened when I assigned the selected rows to the dataframe `DATA`?

Comment: DataFrame.append works not inplace, so need `DATA = DATA.append(df.loc[df['county']==cnty], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @jezrael Oh I'm so stupid... Thank you so much!